# Liferay velocity template showing only first image for repeatable image field

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, velocity, liferay-theme, liferay-velocity

I have created structures and template for adding the events.

The input I have taken is:

1. year with month,
2. image for the event,
3. description for the event.

All the data is displaying properly except image. The image which I have given first is displaying for each event.

Can any one help me?

```
<root available-locales="en_US" default-locale="en_US">
    <dynamic-element dataType="html" fieldNamespace="ddm" indexType="keyword" name="about_fe" readOnly="false" repeatable="false" required="false" showLabel="true" type="ddm-text-html" width="small">
        <meta-data locale="en_US">
            <entry name="label">
                <![CDATA[about fundraising]]>
            </entry>
            <entry name="predefinedValue">
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </entry>
            <entry name="tip">
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </entry>
        </meta-data>
    </dynamic-element>
    <dynamic-element dataType="html" fieldNamespace="ddm" indexType="keyword" name="year_fe" readOnly="false" repeatable="true" required="false" showLabel="true" type="ddm-text-html" width="small">
        <dynamic-element dataType="image" fieldNamespace="wcm" indexType="keyword" name="image_fe" readOnly="false" repeatable="false" required="false" showLabel="true" type="wcm-image" width="">
            <meta-data locale="en_US">
                <entry name="label">
                    <![CDATA[select image for fundraise event]]>
                </entry>
                <entry name="predefinedValue">
                    <![CDATA[]]>
                </entry>
                <entry name="tip">
                    <![CDATA[]]>
                </entry>
            </meta-data>
        </dynamic-element>
        <dynamic-element dataType="html" fieldNamespace="ddm" indexType="keyword" name="desc_fe" readOnly="false" repeatable="false" required="false" showLabel="true" type="ddm-text-html" width="small">
            <meta-data locale="en_US">
                <entry name="label">
                    <![CDATA[enter description for the event]]>
                </entry>
                <entry name="predefinedValue">
                    <![CDATA[]]>
                </entry>
                <entry name="tip">
                    <![CDATA[]]>
                </entry>
            </meta-data>
        </dynamic-element>
        <meta-data locale="en_US">
            <entry name="label">
                <![CDATA[enter the year and month]]>
            </entry>
            <entry name="predefinedValue">
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </entry>
            <entry name="tip">
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </entry>
        </meta-data>
    </dynamic-element>
</root>
```

The following is my template code:

```
#if (!$year_fe.getSiblings().isEmpty())
    #foreach ($cur_year_fe in $year_fe.getSiblings())

    <div class="pto_fund">

        <div class="my_time">
            <div  class="mysection1"><h5>$cur_year_fe.getData()</h5></div>
        </div>

        <div  class="mysection2">
            <img src="$cur_year_fe.image_fe.getData()" height="200px" width="230px"/>
        </div>

        <div  class="mysection3">$cur_year_fe.desc_fe.getData()</div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear">
    </div>
    #end
#end
```

Sample output [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you probably hit below liferay issues :-

https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-43553

https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-51440

Probably the work around would be to move `"image_fe"` to upper level (start with a repeatable image and so on).

HTH

Comment: Instead of  data type for image I changed it to document and media. its working fine.

Comment: Thats the other option :)