# Nested images in a repeteable structure Liferay

Tags: image, nested, liferay, liferay-6, webcontent

It's my first time working with Liferay 6.2 GA2.

I have created a structure for a Web-content that is a text repeatable with an image nested and other texts nested to this text further. And I have created the corresponding template.

My problem is that when I create the Web-content and I repeat this structure, when I select a different image for all the structures the first image appears in all of them and the other images don't appear.

I've read that this is a bug in Liferay but I haven't found a solution yet. I've tried to modify the `main.js` in `ROOT/html/portlet/journal/js` by deleting this code:

```
if (repeatableFieldImage) {
   repeatableFieldImage.remove();
}
```

but it didn't work.

Do you know what's happening and how I can fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Please check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30137395/liferay-velocity-template-showing-only-first-image-for-repeatable-image-field

Comment: ...and check if the problem still persists when you use the latest available version, GA4. No need to hunt for bugs in old releases when there are newer ones around... If the bugs in Lucky Boy's linked question/answer apply to you, they probably are fixed in later releases.